# ¿Generar JSON desde python con codificacion utf-8?

Tags: python

Quiero generar archivos json usando diccionarios en python, el problema que tengo es que **no se visualizan los caracteres con tilde**, en lugar aparece algo como esto:

> descripci\u00f3n.

Generando el *JSON*

[image: 1]
Resultado:

[image: 2]

Comment: El caracter `\u00f3` es justamente la o acentuada `ó` ¿como estás generando el json? adjunta el código.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código en formato texto. Cuando está en modo imagen es muy difícil de leer y reproducir (y en algunos casos, no podemos verlo directamente).

Answer (score 1):

si estas usando la libreria JSON para guardar tus datos en el .json, el método json.dump() tiene un argumento llamado ensure_ascii que se usa para asegurarse que todos los caracteres sean un ascii real. Pero se le puede dar un valor de false para que no modifique la string dada.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
try:
    outgoData[typeOf].append(amount)
    with open('el nombre del archivo a donde vas a guardar', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(outgoData, file, ensure_ascii= False, indent= 4)
    return True
except KeyError:
    return False
```

Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar tu diccionario, incluye `ensure_ascii=False` a la hora de guardalo, así evitas los caracteres ASCII

```
with open('resultado.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fichero:
    str(d).encode('utf-8')
    json.dump(d, fichero, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando el termino de codificacion ASCII de la funcion dump, puedes anularlo quedaria asi el codigo para introducir el contenido de la variable origin en file (json):

```
with open(json_file, 'w') as file:
json.dump(origin, file, ensure_ascii= False, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo se crea un archivo JSON con el array de objetos de los directorios principales de linux, utilizando el encoding utf-8 y asignando ensure_ascii a False para que escriba las vocales con tilde y las ñ y no con código UNICODE

```
palabras_con_tilde = [{name:"árbol"},{name:"café"},{name:"camión"},{name:"niño"}]
    with open('tilde.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as archivo:
        json.dump(palabras_con_tilde, archivo, ensure_ascii=False)
```